# MySQL Select for Update and insert

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, select, insert-update

I am running a multi-threaded application and am facing issues while different threads try to access same records in a particular table.

**Thread A** 
- Wants last record from table "LastOperations" hence does a Select For Update order by ID desc LIMIT 1.
- Creates a new record based on the last record in LastOpertaions table and inserts back into it.

**Thread B**
- Wants last record from table "LastOperations" hence does the same activities as Thread A.

Both Threads are same code. just operating with different data. max alive threads at a time are 4-6 on this table.

**Problem**
If Thread A locks last record with say id 1000, Thread B is taking 999 record and adding new entries into table. The ID field is an auto increment one, which also is the Primary key.

Say Thread 1 is buying Raw Material A and Thread b is buying Raw Material B. Both should deduct from the same account by taking the latest entry. Whats happening is One thread taking older entry from Account, causing errors in account balance.

Any suggestions on what i am missing? any changes needed at DB side?

Comment: The real problem seems to be that you generate the IDs by yourself. Let the DB do that for you

Comment: It isn't clear form your question what you are trying to do.  Are both threads really doing the same thing?  You indicate that Thread B does the same activities as Thread A.

Comment: The IDs are auto incremented by DB.

Comment: Say Threaad 1 is buying Raw Material A and Thread b is buying Raw Material B. Both should deduct from the same account by taking the latest entry. Whats happening is One thread taking older entry from Account, causing errors in account balance.

Comment: Could you provide more information?  Are both threads updating the underlying table?  If so, then I believe that there should be a table lock until the update completes.  Otherwise the database could get really messed up.  Also, can you provide the transaction isolation level that you are using?

Comment: Can you provide the table schema in your question? I ask because it isn't clear if your ID column also the primary key of the table with an [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute.  This will provide an unique index on the number.

Comment: When you create the table, are you using the InnoDB or MyISAM storage engine and what version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem that you are experiencing is the [Transaction Isolation Level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html).  Thread A isn't done creating its record. So, when Thread B obtains the most recent record from "LastOperations" as 999, 999 is truly the last record in the table.

You could change the transaction isolation level to READ UNCOMMITTED (if you have control of your MySQL instance), but that is risky.  If you allow dirty reads, then the complete record generated by Thread A may not be finalized in the database.  (Thus, the 'dirty' in 'dirty read'.)

Comment: Done that at DB side. Still facing issues.

Comment: Agree with dirty reads part. Account being primarily table which everyone needs... this has become point of failure

Comment: Are your statements that are executing within these threads within transactions?  That is, are the statements that you are executing bounded by `BEGIN TRANSACTION` followed by a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`?

Comment: Yes. Transactions are used. Thread takes responsibility of starting and committing/ rollback

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix history and current.  Have two tables:

- `History` that lists all actions; it is mostly `INSERTed` into.
- `Current` that lists the current balance of whatever.  It is mostly `UPDATEd`.

When an action is to occur:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FROM Current ... FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO History ...;
UPDATE Current ...;
COMMIT;
```